# Downloading from NSURL to NSDATA fastly in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsdata, avaudioplayer

I am getting music URL from my API and its duration is 4-5 minutes.Whenever i am trying to convert that URL to data it is consuming lot of time.Is there is any method so that we can convert it fastly.

**This is what i tried:**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void)
{
    data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:trackurl];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
    {
        self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data1 error:nil
        [self.player play];
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't, you can only improve user experience by showing a tips. Or you can load the data as early as possible.

Comment: I assume you're not converting URL to data here, but you're making a network request. And network requests can't be really optimised. I agree with @KudoCC, you should add a loading spinner or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you cannot do much to influence the speed of the internet connection, however perhaps you want to stream the audio rather than downloading it all before starting to play?

If so there is an alternative to `AVAudioPlayer` [here](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer).

This might lead to similar issues if the download speed cannot keep up with play speed, but I think it's the only option.

Incidentally the way you phrase your question is very confusing.  You are not converting a URL into data, you are downloading data using the location specified by a URL.

Comment: I would use streaming instead of downloading, too. Additionally maybe he can download some seconds in advance, if he has an idea of what sounds will be played next.